# gson.toJson(jObj) stackoverflowerror .TypeAdapters$25.write(TypeAdapters.java:704)

Tags: java, json, gson

I am trying to convert a json object to String using gson. Below is the code

```
List<Student> studs = //from db
        int count = studs.size();
        Integer tot_pages= count/limit;
        if(page>tot_pages){
            page=tot_pages;
        }
        Integer start=limit*page-limit;
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        JsonObject jObj= new JsonObject();
        jObj.addProperty("page", page);
        jObj.addProperty("total",tot_pages);
        jObj.addProperty("records",count);
        JsonArray cell = new JsonArray();
        JsonArray rows = new JsonArray();
        JsonObject row= new JsonObject();
        for(Student stud: studs){
            row= new JsonObject();
            row.addProperty("id", stud.getId());
            cell=new JsonArray();
            JsonPrimitive name = new JsonPrimitive(stud.getName());
            JsonPrimitive rollno = new JsonPrimitive(stud.getRollno());
            JsonPrimitive yr = new JsonPrimitive(stud.getYr());
            cell.add(name);
            cell.add(rollno);
            cell.add(yr);
            row.add("cell", row);
            rows.add(row);
            System.out.println(stud.getId());
        }
        System.out.println("done");

        jObj.add("rows", rows);
        System.out.println("done1");
        return gson.toJson(jObj);
```

and getting the error below

> Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError   at
>   java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:416)
>     at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:237)     at
>   java.io.StringWriter.write(StringWriter.java:101)     at
>   com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.string(JsonWriter.java:534)     at
>   com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.writeDeferredName(JsonWriter.java:402)
>     at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.value(JsonWriter.java:495)     at
>   com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$25.write(TypeAdapters.java:686)
>     at
>   com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$25.write(TypeAdapters.java:704)
>     at
>   com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$25.write(TypeAdapters.java:704)
>     at
>   com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$25.write(TypeAdapters.java:704)
>     at
>   com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$25.write(TypeAdapters.java:704)
>     at
>   com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$25.write(TypeAdapters.java:704)
>     at
>   com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$25.write(TypeAdapters.java:704)   <-----this line is repeated many times.

please someone help me out.

Comment: I think you're doing things too complicated... You have a `List<Student>` and you want to serialize it in a JSON string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
row.add("cell", row);
```

To:

```
row.add("cell", cell);
```

On a side note, the `Gson` object is quite powerful, and should be capable of serializing your student list without all the manual code you're using now. Worst come to worst, you should consider creating a [`TypeAdapter`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html) for your student class, registering it with Gson, and serializing as a list:

Hypothetical Student class:

```
public class Student implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String ssn;
    private String schoolId;
    private String firstName;
    private String middleName;
    private String lastName;
    private Calendar enrollDate;

    // Constructors, getters/setters

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Student[%s,%s (%s)]", getLastName(),
                getFirstName(), getSchoolId());
    }
}
```

Corresponding adapter:

```
public class StudentAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Student> {

    public StudentAdapter() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public Student read(final JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
        if (reader.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
            reader.nextNull();
            return null;
        }

        final Student student = new Student();

        reader.beginObject();
        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            final String name = reader.nextName();
            if ("firstName".equals(name)) {
                student.setFirstName(reader.nextString());
            } else if ("lastName".equals(name)) {
                student.setLastName(reader.nextString());
            } else if ("schoolId".equals(name)) {
                student.setSchoolId(reader.nextString());
            }
        }
        reader.endObject();

        return student;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(final JsonWriter writer, final Student student)
            throws IOException {
        if (student == null) {
            writer.nullValue();
            return;
        }

        writer.beginObject();
        writer.name("firstName");
        writer.value(student.getFirstName());
        writer.name("lastName");
        writer.value(student.getLastName());
        writer.name("schoolId");
        writer.value(student.getSchoolId());
        writer.endObject();
    }
}
```

Test code:

```
final List<Student> origStudentList = Arrays.asList(new Student(
        "B12J9", "Samantha", "Cole"), new Student("A09K2", "Adebisi",
        "Onihan"), new Student(null, "Miguel", "Rodriguez"));

final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Student.class,
        new StudentAdapter()).create();

final String json = gson.toJson(origStudentList);
System.out.println(json);

final List<Student> unmarshalledStudentList = gson.fromJson(json,
        new TypeToken<List<Student>>() {
        }.getType());
System.out.println(unmarshalledStudentList);
```

In the above example, I've illustrated how to create an adapter that selectively serializes just the `schoolId`, `firstName` and `lastName` properties of a hypothetical `Student` object. You can use this as a starting point, and there are other examples of type adapters in the Javadoc I linked.

Comment: but i need only few fields from that object what should i do in that case?

Comment: Then you should use a type adapter to get those fields.

Comment: please give an example that would be a great help.

Comment: @user2003821 - I added an example to get you started. Note that there are also examples in the Javadoc I linked in the answer.